# Theme dialog in android

Tags: android, dialog, themes, transparent

I want an activity work as dialog, for this i declared that activity theme in manifest file as:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

But I faced a problem i.e it is creating a duplicate application.
whenever applications are opened, there are 2 applications with the same name.

Comment: Did you forget to paste the rest of your question? Your question seems to be incomplete..

Comment: Do you have the theme tag for an activity or for the whole application? Also, does you problem f 2 applications go away when you remove that line ?